# How to run multiple react apps on a github page?

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I have a monthly report that are done in a react app. It does not call any API but load the data from a json file.
Once a month, I make a build of the app, that will never change. Think of it as an interactive pdf.

I have this structure

```
/CNAME
/index.hml
/2021-05-31/
/2021-04-30/
..
```

Where the index.html looks something like

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <a href="/2021-05-31">2021-05-31</a>
            <a href="/2021-04-30">2021-04-30</a>
        </body>
    </html>
```

The builds are done with

```sh
    cross-env PUBLIC_URL=${PUBLIC_URL} react-scripts build && cp-cli build/index.html build/404.html
    cp -rf build dir/$date
```

When I with the browser visit https://example.com/2021-05-31 , I can see in the log that the app is running, but nothing is rendered.

Is this even possible to accomplish?